# How to limit the number of tags in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tags

I'm using the acts-as-taggable-on gem in my rails application and everything work fine, but i want o limit the number of tags allowed to 5 for example (Like Stackoverflow) so I have searched in the acts-as-taggable-on documentation but didn't find anything, so I'm wondering if this is possible and how can I achieve this?

Actually my code look like this

```
<%= f.text_area :skill_list  %>
```

Comment: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/58

Answer (score 0):

Tags could act as Array.
So in your case try to limit by return `false if array.count > 5`

```
def limit
  raise 'Tooooo long' if array.length > 5
end
```